# No ListBox item in a toolbar

Tags: windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm using  **Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone** and I don't have a **ListBox** item in a Toolbar. Does anybody encountered such problem?

Comment: Are you looking for the ListBox element or the ListBoxItem element (which can't be created via the toolbar) just to be clear?

Comment: @xmashallax the ListBox element cannot be created by a toolbar? I can create it manually - just writing correct code "<ListBox ..." But it is not present in Toolbar (checked under 'all Windows phone controls').

Comment: If you create it via xaml, you can still move it about so should not be an issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ListBox` is available for Windows Phone 8 and you still can use it without any issues, but they decided to remove it from Toolbox (only for Windows Phone 8 projects), because the preffered control is now `LongListSelector`.

From [remarks on LongListSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.longlistselector%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

> It is recommended that you use LongListSelector to display flat lists instead of using a ListBox, as the performance of LongListSelector is better than that of a ListBox and it also supports full data and UI virtualization.